Lebesgue dominated convergence converse - is it true?
Suppose that $f_n:\Omega\to\mathbb{R}$ is a sequence of functions, where $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^N$ is a bounded measurable set such that for a.a. $x\in\Omega$ we have that:
$$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} f_n(x)=f(x)\in\mathbb{R}$$
If we know that $f\in L^1(\Omega)$ can we conclude that:
$$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \int_{\Omega} f_n(x)\ dx=\int_{\Omega} f(x)\ dx$$
?
I don't know how to apply the known results here. Maybe it is not true...but I dont have a counterexample.

No. There are easy examples where $f_n$ is simple with integral $1$, and converges to $f=0$ pointwise a.e

Nope. Consider $f_n(x)=1/n$ and $\Omega=\mathbb{R}$. Then $\int_\Omega f_n=\infty$ but $\int_\Omega f=0$.

I have edited my post. $\Omega$ should be bounded.

Then you still have the standard counterexample of $f_n = n \chi_{(0, 1/n)}$ where $\Omega = (0, 1)$.

There can be two things happening that give you counterexamples:

The functions $f_n$ are not integrable (so the above cannot be true). Take for instance $\Omega=(0,1)$, $f\equiv 0$, and
$$ f_n(x)=\frac 1{nx}. $$
The same could be true just for a subsequence of the $f_n$ and still invalidate the result.

Even if all the $f_n$ are integrable, the limit might not coincide with the integral of $f$, it might be infinite, or it might not exist at all. Again, take $\Omega=(0,1)$, $f\equiv 0$, and respectively


$$ f_n(x)=\sqrt{\frac{n}{\pi}}e^{-nx^2}, $$
$$ f_n(x)=ne^{-\frac{x^2}{n}}$$
$$ f_n(x)=(1+n(1+(-1)^n))e^{-\frac{x^2}{n}}$$
(the limits are respectively $1/2,+\infty$, and non existent).
